# Django: strange not found url error

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django, django-urls

the problem is the next: In my app users can create goals, and all the functions works well. Now I am doing a notification function with ajax polling, and json. And It works fine when the user is new, if the user hasn't create a goal or modify anything, then the notification appears in every template of the app, (and I want that). But, if the user creates a goal, or modify others things in the app (others functionalities of the app that works well) then the notification works bad, because I get the error url not found. The stranger thing is that when the notification doesn't work the console shows:

> Not Found: /list_goal/notify

Or If I am in some url of the app then, the error is

> Not Found: /some-url-of-the-app/notify

But when It works, the console shows:  "GET /notify/ HTTP/1.1" 200 125

So what can I do ?

The code:

goal/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list_goals/$', views.list_goals, name='list_goals'),
    url(r'^list_goals/create/$', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^notify/$', views.notify, name='notify'),
  ... others urls ...
]
```

goal/views.py

```
@login_required
def notify(request):
    user= User.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.is_ajax():
            name = user.name
            data = {"name":name }
            return JsonResponse(data)
    return render(request, 'list_goals.html')

... others views
```

templates/base.html

```
... html code ...
<script>
        (function poll() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: '/notify/',
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function(json) {
                            console.log(json);
                        alert('Notify: your name is: '+ json['name'])
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: poll,
                    timeout: 20000
                })
            }, 5000); // 1000 = 1 SEGUNDO PARA DEBUGGING LO DEJO EN 1 MINUTO.. EN REALIDAD LO CORRECTO SERIA ENTRE 20 Y 40 MINUTOS
        })();

  </script>
```

... more html code...

Comment: can you try to use `{% url 'notify' %}` instead of only 'notify' as url?

Comment: Or at least use an absolute path, with leading slash.

Comment: Thanks, {% url 'notify' %} not work. @DanielRoseman Which is the absolute paht with leading slash of notify ? Can you show me please ?

Comment: sorry the url that I pass in ajax is:  '/notify/', not 'notify'

Comment: can you post the changes you did to test `{% url 'notify' %}`? You have to do `url: "{% url 'notify' %}"` Where `notify` is the **name** of the url, not the url itself.